# Relative Module Error while running webpack/vue-loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, webpack-dev-server, vue-loader

I'm basically trying to run this open source code on my local server:
https://github.com/darosh/oax

I've managed to get to `run node build/dev-server.js` (alias is `npm run webpack:dev`), and got these errors:

build [==                  ] 10%> Starting dev server...
build [==================  ] 91%

ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                                                                                                                                                               15:58:00

These relative modules were not found:

- ../../../plugins/dagre.js in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./components/elements/api/PathChart.vue
- ../../../plugins/graphlib in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./components/elements/api/PathChart.vue
- ./icons-bundle in ./plugins/icons.js
- ./plugins/dagre.js in multi ./build/dev-client ./plugins/lodash.js ./plugins/d3.js ./plugins/dagre.js ./plugins/graphlib.js axios
- ./plugins/graphlib.js in multi ./build/dev-client ./plugins/lodash.js ./plugins/d3.js ./plugins/dagre.js ./plugins/graphlib.js axios
  Build completed in 15.348s

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. The gitignore file was ignoring some packages. In the plugins folder, there were three files that end in .esm.js. I converted those to .js and the file ran smoothly